Enable SMTP in Outlook for Nodemailer to work
I'm having hard time figuring out how to have Nodemailer working with Outlook account. I keep getting Authentication unsuccessful, SmtpClientAuthentication is disabled for the Tenant. Visit https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_disabled for more information
When i go to my outlook account i see Pop is grayed out but i don't see any SMTP settings

I tried following the url but either the doc's not updated or I'm just lost where to change this
